# Why aren't I able to use onClick with an icon using React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-state

I am using react JS and I want to make use of an icon to basically make it look like a dropdown. Screenshot attached to this question.
I am able to call an onClick function using a button but the same code is not working with an i tag. The tutorial I am following may have been outdated. But I want to know the alternative.
Here is my class component.
[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
class Contact extends Component {
    state = {}
    onShowClick = (name, e) => {
        console.log(name);
    };
    render() {
        const { name, email, phone } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className='card card-body mb-3'>
                <h4>{name}{' '} <i onClick={this.onShowClick.bind(this, name)} className='fas fa-sort-down' /></h4>
                <button onClick={this.onShowClick.bind(this, name)}>Button</button>
                <ul className='list-group'>
                    <li className='list-group-item'>E-mail: {email}</li>
                    <li className='list-group-item'>Phone: {phone}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
// PropTypes - TypeChecking
Contact.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    email: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    phone: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
export default Contact;
```

My problem is with the  tag inside the h4 tag.
The function `onShowClick` works perfectly fine with the button but not the icon.
I have used `.bind` and all and yet, I see no results.
How do I get it working?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should really try to add a minimum reproducible example if you want to get help. Is kind of hard to say what is not working properly just from this. Also I tried to add a reproducible example but it seems to be working as you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-rf7tw1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top of my head, without reproducible minimal project, I am thinking of a couple reasons why this wouldn't be working main one being the following:

HTML is not handling your onClick properly because it is wrapped in a h4 and applied on a i tag. I strongly recommend avoiding adding the click events on h and I tags. What you could do here is have a wrapper div, get your h4 inline with your i tag, and wrap the latter with an other div onto which you apply your onClick.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but you have to realize that the `i` element is not a `button`. This element shouldn't handle click events for multiple reasons like keyboard navigation, and ATs. A better practice would be to wrap this icon with a button. You can also reset the css of the button.

```html
<button
  style={{
     border: "none",
     margin: 0,
     padding: 0,
     background: "none"
  }}
  onClick={this.onShowClick.bind(this, name)}
>
   <i className="fas fa-sort-down" />
</button>
```